# is there a way to differentiate Azure activity logs generated by "Microsoft" services versus users and roles in Azure Cloud?

Tags: azure, activitylog

If I look at the Azure activity logs in Azure Portal some of the logs are initiated by Microsoft internal services like "Microsoft Azure Policy Insights". In my application we are getting the Azure activity logs using the Rest API for Activity logs. Is there a way to filter out internally generated logs (initiated by Microsoft Services) from the ones generated by actual users or applications configured in the account? I thought of using caller as a way to differentiate. For users caller has an email address assigned. But the problem with this approach is this approach will filter out any logs for applications as well. Let me if there is any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a way to achieve this scenario.